# Traveling Salesman using Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I am trying to use pyomo to solve TSP problem. I have successfully implemented using python and Gurobi but my Gurobi license expired so I want to now use pyomo and GLPK to implement the TSP problem. This is what I could come up with so far. It is not working the objective value is 0. Can you please help.

```
from pyomo.environ import * 
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
import pyomo.environ

n=13
distanceMatrix=[[0,8,4,10,12,9,15,8,11,5,9,4,10],
    [8,0,7,6,8,6,7,10,12,9,8,7,5],
    [4,7,0,7,9,5,8,5,4,8,6  ,10,8],
    [10,6   ,7,0,6,11,5 ,9,8,12,11,6,9],
    [12,8   ,9,6,   0,7,9,6,9,8,4,11,10],
    [9,6,5,11,7,0,10,4,3,10,6,5,7],
    [15,7   ,8,5,9,10,0,10,9,8,5,9,10],
    [8,10   ,5,9,6,4,10,0,11,5,9,6,7],
    [11,12,4,8, 9,3,9,11,0, 9,11,11,6],
    [5,9,8,12,8,10,8,5,9,0,6,7,5],
       [9,8,6,11,4,6,5,9,11,6,0,10,7],
       [4,7,10,6,11,5,9,6,11,7,10,0,9],
       [10,5,8,9,10,7,10,7,6,5,7,9,0]] 
startCity = 0

model = ConcreteModel()
model.N=Set()
model.M=Set()
model.c=Param(model.N,model.M, initialize=distanceMatrix)
model.x=Var(model.N,model.M, within=NonNegativeReals)
def obj_rule(model):            
    return sum(model.c[n,j]*model.x[n,j] for n in model.N for j in    model.M)
model.obj = Objective(rule=obj_rule,sense=minimize)
def con_rule(model, n):
    return sum(model.x[j,n] for j in model.M if j < n) + sum(model.x[n,j] for j in Model.M if j > i) == 2

model.con = Constraint(model.N, rule=con_rule,doc='constraint1')
opt = SolverFactory("glpk")
results = opt.solve(model)
results.write()
print('Printing Values')
```

Answer (score 5):

The following answer has been tested for Python 3.5.3 and Pyomo 5.1.1.

1. The sets `model.M` and `model.N` have not been initialised.

   This has the effect of declaring empty sets. So if you run:

   ```
   model.con.pprint()
   ```

   you will find that no constraints have been declared. Similarly, `model.obj` is trivially equal to 0 and `model.c` and `model.x` are empty declarations.

   You can fix this with (I'm assuming that you want to index from 1 to n):

   ```
   model.M = Set(initialize=range(1, n+1))
   model.N = Set(initialize=range(1, n+1))
   ```

   Since `model.M` and `model.N` are ranges using a `RangeSet` is probably more suitable, i.e. using the following instead of the above:

   ```
   model.M = RangeSet(n)
   model.N = RangeSet(n)
   ```

   The above Pyomo `RangeSet` is equal to the set {1, 2, ..., n}.

   Furthermore, since `model.M` and `model.N` are the same, declaring one of the sets is sufficient. So if we remove the declaration of `model.N` and replace any reference to `model.N` with `model.M`, we get the same behaviour.
2. The initialisation of `model.c` has to be carried out per `(i, j)` index.

   You can fix this with (using `lambda` function):

   ```
   model.c = Param(model.N, model.M, initialize=lambda model, i, j: distanceMatrix[i-1][j-1])
   ```

   Python lists index from 0, `model.M` and `model.N` start from 1 therefore we use the index `distanceMatrix[i-1][j-1]`.
3. The variables `model.x` are not binary.

   In a TSP, the variables that `model.x` represent are usually binary. Solving the problem after carrying out steps 1 and 2 allows the `model.x` variables to take values such as 2.

   You can change the domain of `model.x` to binary with:

   ```
   model.x = Var(model.N, model.M, within=Binary)
   ```
4. The constraint `model.con` does not allow a TSP tour.

   `model.con` is equivalent to:

   [image: model_con]

   If we take n = 1, `model.con` will cause the TSP solution to have two cities visited from starting city 1 (assuming that the `model.x` are binary), which is not allowed by the definition of TSP.